# My stateful widget does not update the ui, even though I am calling setState and passing the correct value to the widget class

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-state, flutter-build, flutter-future

I ran into a bit of a problem in flutter that I could not figure out myself.

So I have the following code (only the important parts of the code are pasted),

```
class _PrimaryDetailsEditState extends State<PrimaryDetailsEdit> {
  String bankName;  <---------- I have this variable inside my state class

  void _getFormData() {
    BackendApi.call(
        endpoint: APIEndPoints.GET_FORM_DATA,
        data: {'id': widget.jobId},
        onSuccess: (data) {
          setState(() {
            bankName = data['clientBank']['name'];  <-------------- I assign a new value to the above variable here
            print('Bank name is $bankName');  <-------------- This print confirms that the new value has been indeed assigned to the variable
          });
        },
        onFailed: (error) {
          print('Failed to get data');
        });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getFormData();   <------- I call the _getFormData function declared above right here.
    super.initState();
  }
```

In the above code,
 I have a class variable called `bankName` that is of data type string.
 `_getFormData` method defined below the `bankName`, calls another static method called `BackendApi.call()` which is responsible for making an http request to fetch some data. The `BackendApi.call()` takes 4 named parameters and two of the important parameters are `onSuccess` and `onFailed`. These two parameters take callback functions to be called in cases where the data fetching is successful or not.
 As you can see, on `onSuccess` callback I assign some of the data that is received from the http request to the `bankName` variable.
  I also call the `_getFormData` inside the `@override initState()` to make sure that request is issued before the widget is mounted.

## Problem

**Even though `bankName` holds the data I want, when that variable is passed down to a widget, my UI is not updated!**

➡ I am passing the correct variable to the widget to update the UI. I confirmed this by commenting out the `_getFormData` function and initially assigning a value to the `bankName` a value like `bankName = 'Hello'`. If I do this, the UI is updated with the value `Hello`. So I am passing the correct variable to the widget.

Thank you!

Comment: can you share your UI code, and any logs while value is being updated, any errors

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only thing you need to do is to change the row with onSuccess to this:

```
onSuccess: (data) => {
```

When you have it the way it is now:

```
onSuccess: (data) {
```

you are assigning onSuccess to the value of the function and not to the function itself.

Comment: I tried this.... But the result is still the same......